# Creating PGPKEY from NSString public key in ObjectivePGP library

Tags: ios, objective-c, bouncycastle, pgp, openpgp

I'm using an ObjectivePGP [library](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/ObjectivePGP) for PGP encryption is there any possible way to convert the NSString public key to `PGPKey` in ObjectivePGP I can't a find way to convert it to `PGPKey`. I read the documentation from ObjectivePGP no luck

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use:

```
+[ObjectivePGP readKeysFromData:]
```

use

```
NSData *armoredKeyData = [@"string-with-armored-key....." dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
NSArray<PGPKey *> *keys = [ObjectivePGP readKeysFromData:armoredKeyData];
```

`keys` is an array of imported keys, for one key, just get first element.

Comment: i tried with this method [ObjectivePGP readKeysFromData:armoredKeyData]; but it returns nil

Comment: @SunilKumar strange, because this method never should returns `nil`. You can ask on the GitHub repo. Please provide input data with the sample you're using to use: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/ObjectivePGP/issues

Comment: Thanks,  i will create sample and share in github issue  and i have created the question for that over here  also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845758/using-bcpg-public-key-in-objectivepgp-for-generating-pgpkey-its-return-nil