# Using BCPG public key in ObjectivePGP for generating PGPKey its return nil

Tags: objective-c, bouncycastle, pgp, openpgp

My Public key :

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: BCPG v1.48

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
-----END PGP SIGNATURE----

Generating `pgpkey` from  ObjectivePGP libaray
[libaray](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/ObjectivePGP)

Tried with both the types but not able to get `pgpKey`

1)I have used the above publickKeyData   in below code but it returns nil in NSArray of keys

```
   NSData* publickKeyData = [publickKey 
   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSArray<PGPKey *> *keys = [ObjectivePGP readKeysFromData:publickKeyData];
```

2)I have used the above publickKeyData   in below code but it returns nil in PGPPacket

```
  NSUInteger offset = 0; 
  NSUInteger nextPacketOffset = 0;

  PGPPacket * pgpPacket =   [PGPPacketFactory packetWithData:publickKeyData offset:offset nextPacketOffset:&nextPacketOffset];

 NSArray<PGPPacket*> * array = @[pgpPacket];

 PGPPartialKey *pgpPartialKey = [[PGPPartialKey alloc] initWithPackets:array ];

  PGPKey *pgpKey =   [[PGPKey alloc] initWithSecretKey:nil publicKey:pgpPartialKey];

 NSArray<PGPKey *> * pgpKeys =  @[pgpKey];
```

i have tried with both types but not able to get the `PGPKey` from ObjectivePGP [libaray](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/ObjectivePGP), i'm doing wrong this above key works in android with bouncycastle pgp but not in ObjectivePGP

How to solve this problem ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You suppose to attach the public key, but it's not public key.

Answer (score 0):

This question is tracked in the project repository:  https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/ObjectivePGP/issues/93